# Switch stack with only one

Tags: switch, dell

i've two dell switch 1148N
When i set one port for stacking, it automatically set two port:
ex. Te1/0/3....it set also Te1/0/4

Is it possible to create a stack between 2 switches using only one port for each switch?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What switch model? Most stackable switches have a special interface and cable, and you would loop it so that if one link goes bad, you do not split the switches where each thinks it is the stack master.

Comment: Dell 1148 with 4 stackable port but 3 are user for server anche other spf cable...i've only one port

Answer (score 1):

Using a single port for stacking isn't possible with N1000 switches.

> **NOTE:** N1124T-ON/N1148T-ON/N1124P-ON/N1148P-ON/N1500 10G SFP+ ports may
> only be configured as stacking **in adjacent pairs**, e.g. Te1/0/1 and
> Te1/0/2. If configuring all four ports as stacking, the pairs of
> stacking links must be connected to the same unit, i.e. both Te1/0/1-2
> must connect to a single adjacent stack unit.